# Overriding Static Constants in Derived Classes in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, static

First off, I know that you can't override static properties or functions in C#.

Here's what I need.

```
public abstract class Effect
{
   public virtual const float duration = 1.0f;

   public void boo() {
         //do some stuff with duration
   }

   public void foo() {
        //do some other stuff with duration
   }
 }

public class EffectA : Effect
{
    public override const float duration = 3.0f;
}
```

There's some other stuff in the base and derived class, but the part that I'm having trouble with is this static constant.  I need to refer it from other sections of code WITHOUT an instance, e.g. EffectA.duration.  A function/property would also be fine, but those also can not be overriden if static.

I've seen similar questions, but all the answers seem to involve non-static solutions, i.e. instead of making it a static function, make it an instance function.  In my case, in the places where I want to query EffectA.duration, it would not be desirable to create an instance.  Also, I'd prefer not to have an instance variable since in reality it's these classes are Unity3D Monobehaviours, and it wouldn't make much sense to have a static instance since there are many being created and destroyed at various points.

What is the ideal work around if I want to be able to share the code in boo and still have access to the static duration for each derived class.

Here's a modified version of the relevant portion of the current code:

```
public abstract class Effect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual float kDuration { get { return 1.0f; }}

    public float elapsed = 0.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        elapsed = kDuration;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    protected virtual void FixedUpdate()
    {
        elapsed -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        if(elapsed <= 0) {
            Destroy(this);
        }

        _doEffect();
    }

    protected abstract void _doEffect();
}

public class EffectA : Effect
{
    public override float kDuration { get {return 3.0f; } }

    protected override void _doEffect()
    {
        //Some behavior
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is there's no static way to access kDuration for an Effect, and there are many portions in the code where I need to be able to get EffectA.kDuration or something similar without an instance.

Comment: The answer is simple - you cannot do this without involving "non-static solutions". However, you can make non-static solution applicable to you. The question is "How are you going to use this?" Show some code of how you expect it to be used.

Comment: In C#, classes themselves are not objects (only instances of classes are), and it makes no sense whatsoever to want to "override" _any_ static member. But even if you could, how do you think you'd _use_ an override? What is it you want to do that can't be done simply by hiding (with `public new const float duration = 3.0f;`) the base class member? _"I'd prefer not to have a static instance variable"_ -- I don't even know what that means. What in the world would a "static instance variable" be?

Comment: I updated the question with more code to show how I'm trying to use this.

"static instance variable" was a typo; I meant instance variable.  The reason I can't use an override is that the code I want to share is in the base class, Effect, so if I made it a static override, then in the code above the Start() function would always use kDuration from the base class Effect, instead of the kDuration for the class that the object actually belongs to as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a bit strange, but one option to keep them static and provide new value/implementation is to just *hide* the inherited members, by simply using the same name:

```
public abstract class Effect
{
    public const float duration = 1.0f;

    public static void boo()
    {
        // this prints 1.0f
        Console.WriteLine(duration);
    }
}

public class EffectA : Effect
{
    public new const float duration = 3.0f;

    public new static void boo()
    {
        // this prints 3.0f
        Console.WriteLine(duration);
    }
}
```

Note the `new` keyword just gets rid of the compiler warning for you, using the same name is what results in hiding.

**Update**

Based on your comment, here's how you can avoid duplication and just call the shared implementation:

```
public abstract class Effect
{
    public const float duration = 1.0f;

    public static void boo(float val = duration)
    {
        // your complex shared implementation
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
}

public class EffectA : Effect
{
    public new const float duration = 3.0f;

    public new static void boo()
    {
        Effect.boo(duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the case where boo() is more complicated and uses duration in multiple places, this would require copy-pasting boo to each derived class, right?  And if I need to change that behavior, I would need to change it in each copy-pasted location.

Ideally, I would be able to share the code, since it's the same for each Effect.

Comment: @StackedAE Not necessarily. You can refactor the "shared" code into a reusable method, and then just call that from derived classed. Look at the update.

Comment: So in this case you have to also define a new static void boo() in each derived class, right?  If you happened to define only a new duration, but forgot to put a new boo() in a derived class, then the duration field would not match the actual behavior of the derived class, which seems dangerous.  Also, if we have multiple functions in the base class that we want to share that use duration (which is actually the case in my application), then we'd have to make a dummy override function for each of them in each derived class.

There's no way to make this happen automatically?

Comment: @StackedAE yes, it will use the parent's if you forget to define one which would also happen if the members weren't static. No silver bullets to guard you against forgetting stuff I'm afraid, although having unit tests can help. If you want to keep things simple, maybe inheritance isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Could try this but may not be the right approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" duration from Effect " + Effect.duration);
        Console.WriteLine(" duration from EffectA " + EffectA.duration);
        Console.WriteLine(" duration from EffectB " + EffectB.duration);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Effect
{
    public const float duration = 1.0f;
}
class EffectA : Effect
{
    public const float duration = 3.0f;
}
class EffectB : Effect
{
}
```

The result should be :

```
duration from Effect 1
duration from EffectA 3
duration from EffectB 1
```

There will be a `warning` in Visual Studio 2015 but can be by passed.
Not sure whether can work with `Unity3D MonoDevelop`.

Comment: In the boo() function of Effect I am trying to share code that will use the duration for the class of the particular object.  So the instance function needs to access the static variable, but the instance function should use the static variable belonging to class that the instance is.  If I just make it an override and reference "duration" in the base class, then it would be the duration defined in Effect, rather than the duration of the desired class.